# Selección de Múltiples checkbox en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, post, checkbox

Resulta que quiero seleccionar solo unos datos de  mi BD pero solo me trae un valor en forma de array.

Este procedimiento lo estoy haciendo con un checkbox y un botón para seleccionar los datos.

Este es el formulario como se puede ver selecciono y envio, pero al momento de enviar solo me trae un valor y la idea es que me traiga los dos arrays y no solo uno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de la consulta :

```
switch ($action) {

case 'seleccionar':
    $sentencia = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE idProducto='$idProducto'");
    $dato = $sentencia->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    print_r($dato);
    $nombreProducto = $dato['nombreProducto'];
    $n_Parte_Pruducto = $dato['n_Parte_Pruducto'];
    $marcaPruducto = $dato['marcaPruducto'];
    echo "Aprimiste Seleccionar ";
    break;
}
```

Este es el código de la tabla:

```
<?php foreach ($set_producto as $dato) { ?>
                                <tr class="table-light">
                                    <td><?php echo $dato['idProducto']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $dato['marcaPruducto']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $dato['nombreProducto']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $dato['n_Parte_Pruducto']; ?></td>
                                    
                                    
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                        <form action="" method="POST">  
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $dato['idProducto']; ?>" name='idProducto'>
                                        <td><input type="submit" value="seleccionar" class="btn btn-info" name="action">
                                        </td>   
                                        </div>
                                     </td>

                                    
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Quedo atento a su amable ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, debes editar tu pregunta y  poner el código como texto y no en imágenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia ya lo realice

Comment: Creo que sería mejor poner un botón en la parte superior que enviara un array con los `idProducto` seleccionados y componer en la sentencia sql con un `OR`: `where idProducto='$idProducto[0]' OR idProducto='$idProducto[1]' ...`